# Match alpha letters and accented alpha letters

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I'm looking for some regex code with this pattern:

- Must contain at least 1 of the following and match the whole string.
- Can contain only alpha letters (a-z A-Z) ...
- and accented alpha letters (á ä à etc).

I'm using `preg_match('/^([\p{L}]*)$/iu', $input)`, but `\p{L}` matches all unicode letters, including Chinese. I just want to allow the English alphabet letters but also the accented variants of them.

So `JohnDoe`, `Fübar`, `Lòrem`, `FírstNäme`, `Çákë` would all be valid inputs, because they all contain at least 1 alpha letter and/or accented alpha letters, and the whole string matches.

Comment: [[:alpha:]] doesn't solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this compact regex:

```
(?i)(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[a-zÀ-ÿ])+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bH3mM5).

1. This regex takes advantage of the fact that the accented letters you want all seem to live in the Unicode character range from `À` to `ÿ` (see this [table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)), so we simply add it to the character class.
2. The `À-ÿ` has a few unwanted characters. Unlike some engines, `PCRE` (PHP's regex engine) does not support character class subtraction, but we mimic it with the negative lookahead `(?![×Þß÷þø])`
3. Be aware that some characters such as `à` can be expressed by several Unicode code points (the `à` grapheme, or an `a` with a grave accent). This will only match the non-combined graphemes. Catching all variations is really hard.

In your code:

```
$regex = "~(?i)(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[a-zÀ-ÿ])+~u";
$hit = preg_match($regex,$subject,$match);
```

Comment: That's awesome! It wasn't working in JavaScript, this modification does work in PCRE, JavaScript and Python: (?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ])+

Comment: @JuanGarcia Yes, that's a lovely way to do it. I often use this method for custom ranges. Thanks for the upvote btw (I assume it was you. :) )

Comment: Please, update the answer to support all. That can be useful for someone else

Comment: @JuanGarcia Each engine has its own way of turning on the case-insensitive mode. I want to use it in my answer. If someone reads the answer and wants to use it in JS, they can add the mode like this: `/(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[a-zÀ-ÿ])+/i`

Comment: This is a very nice regex zx81! It's missing beginning `^` and end `$` anchors but seems to work well if they're added in. I think the `iconv` solution I proposed on this page may match a few more accents although I've given this +1 as it answers the question using pure regex.

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample data as well as some Chinese & Japanese characters, the regex `/[!\p{Common}\p{Latin}]*/iu` seems to work. For more details, this site has some nice background on [predefined Unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) as well as a nice [simple explanation here](http://brugbart.com/allow-certain-characters-php). But it does return an empty match for the non-Latin characters in this version. The one in my **EDIT:** at the bottom will be best for clean boolean logic:

```
// Set a test array.
$test_array = array();
$test_array[] = 'JóhnDoe';
$test_array[] = 'Fübar';
$test_array[] = 'Lòrem';
$test_array[] = 'FírstNäme';
$test_array[] = '•••••••';
$test_array[] = 'Çákë';
$test_array[] = '形声字 / 形聲字';
$test_array[] = 'ラドクリフ、マラソン';

 // Set the header for debugging output.
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// Roll through the test array.
foreach ($test_array as $test_value) {

  // Run a regex to detect latin and common characters.
  preg_match('/[!\p{Common}\p{Latin}]*/iu', $test_value, $matches);

  // Kludge using array filtering to get rid of empty matches.
  $matches = array_filter($matches);

  // Dump the matches for debugging.
  print_r($matches);

}
```

The output is as follows: Note how the Chinese & Japanese characters return empty matches. Also note how the `•••••••` comes through thanks to the `\p{Common}` regex match. If you don’t want common characters like that to come through, just change the regex to be, `/[!\p{Latin}]*/iu`. I am using [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to clean out those empty values, but it is kludgy. So this is not perfect, but serviceable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => JóhnDoe
)
Array
(
    [0] => Fübar
)
Array
(
    [0] => Lòrem
)
Array
(
    [0] => FírstNäme
)
Array
(
    [0] => •••••••
)
Array
(
    [0] => Çákë
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

**EDIT:** This test code uses a variant of the regex I posted above to eliminate the empty non-match issue above; `/(?:[\p{Latin}])+/iu`. Note this works by only matching against `\p{Latin}` so `\p{Common}` won’t play well here. But the results using `/(?:[\p{Latin}])+/iu` are cleaner and assure you can use a simple boolean check of `preg_match` to check for characters instead of having to use a kludge that mixes the `$matches` array with `array_filter`:

```
// Set a test array.
$test_array = array();
$test_array[] = 'JóhnDoe';
$test_array[] = 'Fübar';
$test_array[] = 'Lòrem';
$test_array[] = 'FírstNäme';
$test_array[] = '•••••••';
$test_array[] = 'Çákë';
$test_array[] = '形声字 / 形聲字';
$test_array[] = 'ラドクリフ、マラソン';

 // Set the header for debugging output.
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// Roll through the test array.
foreach ($test_array as $test_value) {

  // Run a regex to detect latin and common characters.
  preg_match('/(?:[\p{Latin}])+/iu', $test_value, $matches);

  // Dump the matches for debugging.
  print_r($matches);

}
```

And the new results are as follows. Note that the empty arrays are truly empty and the `prey_match` will return a boolean `false` in those cases:

```
Array
(
    [0] => JóhnDoe
)
Array
(
    [0] => Fübar
)
Array
(
    [0] => Lòrem
)
Array
(
    [0] => FírstNäme
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => Çákë
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

Comment: after reading later posted zx81 answer, I think it deserves top in this question. His compact elegant regexp with my update now will work in PCRE, JavaScript and Python, it can be really useful for somebody else

Comment: It shouldn't be valid when I input something like `!Jóhn`. The whole string is supposed to be only alpha letters and/or accented variants.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution using a combination of `preg_match` and `iconv`. Tested with php 5.5 on Windows and Linux:

```
$testWords = array(
    // pass
    'Çákë',
    'JohnDoe',
    'Fübar',
    'Lòrem',
    'FírstNäme',
    // fail
    'Ç@kë',
    'J0hnDoe',
    'F行bar',
    'L高rem',
    'F前rstNäme',
    'Ç学kë',
    '0'
);

$matchedWords = array_filter($testWords, function ($word) {
    // these characters should not be in the search string but may appear after iconv conversion
    $regexCharsNot = '\^~"`\'';

    $valid = false;

    if (!preg_match("/[$regexCharsNot]/u", $word)) {
        if ($word = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $word)) {
            $valid = preg_match("/^[A-Za-z$regexCharsNot]+$/u", $word);
        }
    }

    return $valid;
});

echo print_r($matchedWords, true);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Çákë
    [1] => JohnDoe
    [2] => Fübar
    [3] => Lòrem
    [4] => FírstNäme
)
 */
```

`iconv` and `ASCII//TRANSLIT` introduces extraneous characters which is why the `$regexCharsNot` double validation is required. I came up with that list using the following:

```
// mb_str_split regex           http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php#99851
// list of accented characters  http://fasforward.com/list-of-european-special-characters/

$accentedCharacters = preg_split(
    '/(?<!^)(?!$)/u',
    'ÄäÀàÁáÂâÃãÅåĄąĂăÆæÇçĆćĈĉČčĎđĐďðÈèÉéÊêËëĚěĘęĜĝĢģĤĥÌìÍíÎîÏïĴĵĶķĹĺĻļŁłĽľÑñŃńŇňÖöÒòÓóÔôÕõŐőØøŒœŔŕŘřßŚśŜŝŞşŠšŤťŢţÞþÜüÙùÚúÛûŰűŨũŲųŮůŴŵÝýŸÿŶŷŹźŽžŻż');

/*
$unsupported = ''; // 'Ǎǎẞ';

foreach ($accentedCharacters as $c) {
    if (!@iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $c)) {
        $unsupported .= $c;
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting idea, but did you mean for `^~"` to be `[^~"]` (typo)?

Answer (score 0):

Accented alpha letters are unicode characters by their own completely unrelated with their unaccented variants. It may seen related to each other by a human observer, but a computer will have no way of knowing the difference by comparing it with alpha characters of the standard ascii set.
A way to achieve this is by providing to your regexp by a whitelist of which characters are allowed.
In case you don't need the accented characters, another way is using an library like Apache Lucene (which is a Java library, but I think I have read it can be use in PHP) will replace the accented characters for their unaccented variants with the right analyzer/s.